# How to subscribe inside a for loop in rx way and save emitted values to one array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to display save a value in an array from multiple button toggles in an RX way.

I've tried using mergeMap and then forkJoin but no luck

Heres an example:

HTML:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group
      #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
      multiple="true"
      (change)="change($event)">
        <mat-button-toggle
          *ngFor="let currency of currencies"
          [value]="currency">
          {{ currency }}
        </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Example Currency value:

Toggle USD Button

> [“USD”]

Toggle PH Button

> [“USD”, “PH”]

TS:

```
instruments: Instruments = []
 change(currency: any): void {
    // Currency values is: ["USD", "PH"]
    for (var i = 0; i < currency.value.length; i++) {
      this.instrumentService
        .getRepoCurrency(currency.value[i])
        .subscribe(repo => {
          // repo is of type Response 
          this.instruments = repo.json();
        });
    }
  }
```

I expected the output to be:

```
[{USD1},{USD2}..., {PH1}, {PH2}...]
```

but the actual output is on console

```
[{USD1},{USD2}..]
[{PH1}, {PH2}..]
```

Comment: So you want to add the different Currency when you toggle each different currency button Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Thivagar basically yes. You toggle a button, it adds the data to an array, you add another one it adds to an existing array

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, use forkJoin and Spread Syntax. Because you're looping through the array right, it's better to use forkJoin

```
change(currency: any): void {
// Currency values is: ["USD", "PH"]
  let currencyForkArray:any[]=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < currency.value.length; i++) {
   currencyForkArray.push(this.instrumentService.getRepoCurrency(currency.value[i]));           
  });
  forkJoin(currencyForkArray).subscribe(repo => {
   repo.forEach((r:any)=>{
      this.instruments  =[...this.instruments , r.json()];
   })         
})
```

Comment: Stil getting the value: 

2[Array(45), Array(9)]

should be:
54 [{...}]

Comment: Now edited the my answer. try now and see what u getting

Comment: having an issue on this part forkJoin(currencyForkArray).subscribe(repo => {
      instruments = repo.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
      ...acc, cur.json()
      }, []) 

saying that concat is not a function

Comment: Fixed it already but what I did was:  this.instruments = await repo.reduce((prev, current) => { return [...prev, ...current.json()]; }, []);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a new function to add the currency to the array each time you toggle the currency button. Then bind that function to 's click event.

```
instruments: Instruments = [];

change(currency): void {
    this.instruments.push(currency);
}
```

Then in your HTML do like this

```
<mat-button-toggle
      *ngFor="let currency of currencies"
      [value]="currency" (click)="change(currency)">
      {{ currency }}
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Now this will add the respective currency to your array.
I hope this helps.